# Solve $y'=a(x)y^2+b(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

**PROBLEM**
Solve $$y'=a(x)y^2+b(x)$$

$a(x) = \frac{a_1}{m-M x} , b(x) = \frac{b_1-(m-M x)b_2}{m-M x} $ and $a_1,m,M,b_1,b_2 $ are constants

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

I find on net it's probably *Riccati Equation* and they are computed by substitution.
Any ideas on solving this equation?

Comment: It's not linear to solve the homogeneous part first. Without knowing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ functions you can hardly solve it

Comment: I know exactly functions $a$ and $b$, but i thought it can be done in general way. They are little bit complicated.

Comment: Culak, there is no general solution for this equation. It's better to write what a and b are as functions to get some help.

Comment: So I edit it by simpler version of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y'=a(x)y^2+b(x)\tag 1$$
Equation $(1)$ is a Riccati ODE.

The change of function :
$\quad y=-\frac{1}{a(x)}\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}\quad$
transforms it into a linear second order ODE:
$$a(x)u''-a'(x)u'+(a(x))^2b(x)u=0\tag 2$$
Since the analytical solutions of only a few linear second order ODEs are known on the form of combination of a finite number of elementary and special functions, there is no general method to express the solutions of equation $(2)$ on explicit form.

Thus there is no general method to express the solutions of equation $(1)$ on explicit form. This can be done only in some particular cases depending on the kind of functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$.

Analytical solving is possible in the case of 
$a(x) = \frac{a_1}{m-M x} , b(x) = \frac{b_1-(m-M x)b_2}{m-M x} $

Compute $a'(x)$ and put it into equation $(2)$ as well as $b(x)$. This leads to an equation of Bessel kind. Eq.(6) in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) details how to reduce it to a second order linear equation.